# Theorem Reference Query: $p'$-Elements in Supersolvable Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I have the following question: In the context of a finite supersolvable group $G$, where $p$ represents the largest prime divisor of $|G|$, I would like to inquire about a specific theorem, for which I am seeking a reference. The theorem concerns the behavior of $p'$-elements in such groups. Specifically, if the $p'$-elements of $G$ act as power automorphisms on the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, does this theorem, attributed to Huppert (reference needed), state that either the Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ must be abelian or that the $p'$-elements of $G$ centralize $P$?

If anyone can provide a reference for this theorem, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps: on page $34$ in Roland Schmidt's book, *[Subgroup Lattices of Groups](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110868647/html)*, de Gruyter 1994, (and [here](https://dokumen.tips/documents/subgroup-lattices-of-groups-department-of-mathematics-lattices-of-groups-by-roland.html?page=4)) Exercise, no.5. It reads: If $P$ is a non-abelian $p$-group, then the group of power automorphisms of $P$ is a $p$-group. Reference is made to an article by Huppert, in Archiv Math., **12**, (1961), pp. 161-169, entitled: *Zur Sylowstruktur auflösbarer Gruppen*. In the case you mention, it concerns a supersolvable group $G$ where $p$ is the largest prime dividing $|G|$. Such a $G$ has a *normal* Sylow $p$-subgroup. Incidentally, the group of power automorphisms of a finite group is abelian. That's in Schmidt's book Theorem I.5.1. Hope this helps!

Comment: ,: Thank you for your quick response and the valuable reference to Roland Schmidt's book. I appreciate your help in clarifying the concept I was inquiring about.

Comment: You are welcome!